# Why am I getting Promise Pending despite using await in my controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a repository where I connect directly to my model to insert some data, it creates the data successfully but when I connect my controller to this repository, I get a nulled response, if I log it in the repository itself I get Promise  . Please checkout my code below:-

**Repository.js**

```
exports.register = (request) => {
  const data = UserModel.findOne({email: request.email})
    .then(user => {
        if(user)
        {
            return {status: 400, message: 'Email Already exist'}
        } else {
            return bcrypt.genSalt(10,  (err, salt) => {
                const newUser = new UserModel({
                    username: request.username,
                    email: request.email,
                    password: request.password
                });

                return bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, async (err, hash) => {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    newUser.password = hash;
                    return newUser.save()
                        .then(user => {
                            const token = jwt.sign({id: user._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                                expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
                            });
                            return {status: 200, message: 'Successfully Registered', auth: true, token: token, user: user}
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            return {status: 400, message: err}
                        })
                })
            })
        }
})

  console.log(data) // This part is return Promise <pending>
  return data;
};
```

**Controller.js**

```
exports.SeedRegisteration = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let element = await userRepo.register({username: "Testin", email: "Testin@test.com", "password": 
 "joe" });
      return await res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: element })
 } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: e.message });
 }
};
```

Works fine but does not return data

Comment: your exports.register function doesn't return anything - oh, sorry, it probably does ... weird formatting

Comment: see this `return bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, async function (err, hash) {` that doesn't return what you hope it does, you'll need to promisify that

Comment: `bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) =>` will need promisifaction too

Comment: The problem still persist even if I remove the bcrypt function

Comment: actually - bcrypt does have "promise" versions - you just need to use those

Comment: Can you help edit the code?

Comment: yes, I can do that

Comment: I've done it on my end using the bcypt promise version like you said and it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `register` function using the Promise version of bcrypt (if you don't supply a callback, the bcrypt functions return a Promise

```
exports.register = (request) => 
    UserModel.findOne({
            email: request.email
    })
    .then(user => {
        if (user) {
            throw 'Email Already exist'
        }
    })
    .then(() => bcrypt.genSalt(10))
    .then(salt => {
        const newUser = new UserModel({
                username: request.username,
                email: request.email,
                password: request.password
            });

        return bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt)
        .then((hash) => {
            newUser.password = hash;
            return newUser.save();
        })
    }).then(user => {
        const token = jwt.sign({
            id: user._id
        }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
        });
        return {
            status: 200,
            message: 'Successfully Registered',
            auth: true,
            token: token,
            user: user
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return {
            status: 400,
            message: err
        }
    });
```

Note: there is ONE nested .then - this code could be perfectly flat if you used async/await in `register` - however I was not prepared to perform such a big rewrite for the answer. Now that the code is in a nice almost flat promise chain, it's relatively simple to convert the whole thing into async/await style

Answer (score -1):

There are too many `return` statements which return promise. Please update your code in to the following:

```
    exports.register = (request) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            UserModel.findOne({ email: request.email })
                .then(user => {
                    if (user) {
                        return reject({ status: 400, message: 'Email Already exist' })
                    } else {
                        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
                            const newUser = new UserModel({
                                username: request.username,
                                email: request.email,
                                password: request.password
                            });

                            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, async (err, hash) => {
                                if (err) return reject(err);
                                newUser.password = hash;
                                newUser.save()
                                    .then(user => {
                                        const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                                            expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
                                        });
                                        return resolve({ status: 200, message: 'Successfully Registered', auth: true, token: token, user: user })
                                    })
                                    .catch(err => {
                                        return reject({ status: 400, message: err })
                                    })
                            })
                        })
                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    return reject(err)
                })
        } catch (error) {
            return reject(error)
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't think the promise here is really needed, Jaromanda X seems to be straight forward without having to touch the controller

Comment: Well, you are not actually touching the controller. I have just updated `Repository` file. In your `controller`, you already have `try/catch` any way

Comment: this code demonstrates the perfect use of the Promise constructor anti-pattern ... `UserModel.findOne` returns a Promise, so why wrap it in `new Promise`. Also, the bcrypt methods do return Promises if you do not supply a callback argument, so why not use promise chaining to your full advantage, to make neat code without the callback pyramid of doom you've got going in there

Comment: Hmm. I understand the `promise anti-pattern` argument here. Thanks for pointing it out